# i want to redirect home url from custome login page in magento

Tags: magento-1.7

i hope this would be very simple question for expert but not for me.

i just want, when my site url is opened then its auto redirect to customer login page 
but condition is 
when customer is logged  and if he clicks on home link then show customer dashboard or customer info.

Can someone help me please provided me any solution,i am using magento 1.7.X

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Any one suggest me any soultion ??

Comment: For resolve this i have made .phtml page in page/html and access by  cms block with                                                  {{block type='core/template' template='page/html/custom_login.phtml'}} this code is working bcaz i echo on .phtml file its showing but code what i have used for login condition. its not working please some one help ..its very urgent for me

Comment: My problem got resolve i made csm page and

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My problem got resolve i made cms page and enter this code

```
{{block type='core/template' template='page/html/custom_login.phtml'}}
```

then i made the page and code-

```
`<?php //Check If Customer Is Logged In Or Not.
 if (!Mage::getSingleton("customer/session")->isLoggedIn())
      {
        $session = Mage::getSingleton("customer/session");
        // Store The Current Page Url Where User will be redirected once loggedin
        $session->setBeforeAuthUrl(Mage::helper("core/url")->getCurrentUrl());
        $customerLoginURL = $this->getBaseUrl() . "customer/account/login";
         Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()>setRedirect($customerLoginURL)-       >sendResponse();
        }else{
        //redirect to login
        $customerLoginURL = $this->getBaseUrl() . "customer/account/login";
        Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect($customerLoginURL)->sendResponse();
        }
        ?>`
```

if any one want to help for this can ask me comment on this